# I facing Issue in Swagger api?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-codegen, swagger-editor, swagger-node-express

**Swagger.yml**

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  version: "0.0.1"
  title: Movie DB
# during dev, should point to your local machine
host: localhost:8000
# basePath prefixes all resource paths 
basePath: /
# 
schemes:
  # tip: remove http to make production-grade
  - http
  - https
# format of bodies a client can send (Content-Type)
consumes:
  - application/json
# format of the responses to the client (Accepts)
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /movies:
    # binds a127 app logic to a route
    x-swagger-router-controller: movies
    get:
      description: Returns 'Hello' to the caller
      # used as the method name of the controller
      operationId: index
      parameters:
        - name: name
          in: query
          description: The name of the person to whom to say hello
          required: false
          type: string
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Success
          schema:
            # a pointer to a definition
            $ref: "#/definitions/MovieListBody"
        # responses may fall through to errors
        default:
          description: Error
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/ErrorResponse"
  /swagger:
    x-swagger-pipe: swagger_raw
# complex objects have schema definitions

    post:
      description: Creates a new movie entry
      operationId: create
      parameters:
        - name: movie
          required: true
          in: body
          description: a new movie details
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/MovieBody"
      responses:
        "200":
          description: a successfully stored movie details
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/MovieBody"
        default:
          description: Error
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/ErrorResponse" 

definitions:
  MovieListBody:
    required:
      - movies
    properties:
      movies:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: "#/definitions/Movie"

  Movie:
    required:
      - title
      - gener
      - year
    properties:
      title:
        type: string
      gener:
        type: string
      year:
        type: integer

  MovieBody:
    required:
      - movie
    properties:
      movie:
        $ref: "#/definitions/Movie"

  ErrorResponse:
    required:
      - message
    properties:
      message:
        type: string
```

I Get this error:

> Route defined in Swagger specification (/movies) but there is no defined post operation

I am new to this concept of Swagger API. I tried crud operation in Swagger API. The `get` method is working fine, but I tried `post` showing this type of issue. I tried step by step watching Swagger API videos. I tried get function is data successfully retrieved in db.but I tried post data to mongodb using Swagger API it's throwing this type of error....

How to fix it? Can anyone suggest any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `/swagger` node, just a `post` node at the same level as the `get` node under `/movies` path.
POST and GET are operations that can be performed on the 'movies' endpoint.

At present, your swagger supports `GET /movies/` and `POST /swagger/` as you've got a path called 'swagger'.

The structure should become:

```
paths:
  /movies:
    get:
      # All the get properties
    post:
      # All the post properties
definitions:
  # All the definitions you need
```

And here's an updated copy of your swagger:

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  version: "0.0.1"
  title: Movie DB
# during dev, should point to your local machine
host: localhost:8000
# basePath prefixes all resource paths 
basePath: /
# 
schemes:
  # tip: remove http to make production-grade
  - http
  - https
# format of bodies a client can send (Content-Type)
consumes:
  - application/json
# format of the responses to the client (Accepts)
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /movies:
    # binds a127 app logic to a route
    x-swagger-router-controller: movies
    get:
      description: Returns 'Hello' to the caller
      # used as the method name of the controller
      operationId: index
      parameters:
        - name: name
          in: query
          description: The name of the person to whom to say hello
          required: false
          type: string
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Success
          schema:
            # a pointer to a definition
            $ref: "#/definitions/MovieListBody"
        # responses may fall through to errors
        default:
          description: Error
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/ErrorResponse"
    post:
      description: Creates a new movie entry
      operationId: create
      parameters:
        - name: movie
          required: true
          in: body
          description: a new movie details
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/MovieBody"
      responses:
        "200":
          description: a successfully stored movie details
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/MovieBody"
        default:
          description: Error
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/ErrorResponse" 
definitions:
  MovieListBody:
    required:
      - movies
    properties:
      movies:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: "#/definitions/Movie"

  Movie:
    required:
      - title
      - gener
      - year
    properties:
      title:
        type: string
      gener:
        type: string
      year:
        type: integer

  MovieBody:
    required:
      - movie
    properties:
      movie:
        $ref: "#/definitions/Movie"

  ErrorResponse:
    required:
      - message
    properties:
      message:
        type: string
```

Comment: I've updated the answer with the correct hierarchy.

Comment: I tried this structure but this throwing this different error
"message": "Request validation failed: Parameter (movie) failed schema validation",

Comment: can give me Swagger api crud operation example code or videos...plz

Comment: I've updated the answer with an updated version of your swagger which is syntactically valid.

Comment: I tried this pattern but throwing this type error Error: Response validation failed: failed schema validation.how to solve this error.and can you explain what this error

Comment: Can any one check my yaml file I tried exceuting post method .its throwing erro schema validation failed.How to handle it.give me any solution..plz